# Can One OS Affect Another In Dual-Booted System?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, kubuntu

I'm dual-booting Windows 10 (the original OS) and Kubuntu 14.04.
My Kubuntu installation doesn't recognize wireless (the QCA6164 Driver issue) so I tried using ndiswrapper to solve the issue. This I didn't expect that while in my Kubuntu boot I also have access to the windows side through Dolphin.

Since I needed to have the Windows drivers to install with ndiswrapper and could not find an available zip to download, I went into the Windows side and copied the files from there to no avail.

The thing is that while on the Windows OS I ran a diagnostic test and it returned an invalid PCI/PCI-e on the test. I used Systemback to restore my Kubuntu after the failed driver solution attempt.

My question is if I made changes to one OS could it directly affect the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short NO just adding drivers to Ubuntu will not affect Windows, they are on different partitions and do not interact, however if you mount you Windows partition in Ubuntu (or Ubuntu in Windows via a third party app) and modify any system files, this could potentially break Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If either partition is mounted (I doubt W10 can mount Ext4) then yes they can touch each other. If Windows does a nasty thing and pokes at/reads off your Ubuntu partition, it just did.

Windows can parse partition maps but not Ext4 - like one might be able to copy German but not read it.

Linux can read Ext4 but the odds of it mounting your Windows partition without you telling it to or adding it to fstab is very unlikely.

Comment: Reads off you're referring to in the test I ran on the Windows side? I did tell Linux to mount windows, that's how I pulled the driver files from the windows side to use with ndiswrapper. So the "to the point" question is, by installing drivers to Linux can that affect windows in plain english, yes or no. Then if you'd like to share the how and why that would be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'll explain better. It can't. Windows and Linux basically are isolated unless you explicitly tell them to not do so.